# Landscape UI does not show on iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have an app to run in landscape mode only. I tested on iPhone 4, 4s, 5, 5s, 6. It works as expected. However, when I tested it on iphone 6+, with the simulator. Two out of three pages were broken. For the broken pages, only the navigationbar appears. The rest UI did not show up.

Why would this happen? What is the difference for iPhone 6 plus?
storyboard
[image: storyboard]
constrains on the image
[image: constrains on the image]
does not work in landscape
[image: does not work in landscape]
work in portrait
[image: work in portrait]

Comment: No, no one has a clue because there is no information to base a guess on. Could you provide some more info. Code, storyboard screenshots, etc... Will make it a lot easier to help then.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am still confused because I do not know which part of code or storyboard should be the suspect.

Comment: Well, neither do we. If you can make a guess or show a screenshot of your app to show what is/isn't happening it might give us something to go on? Are you using auto layout? Have you changed the size classes in the storyboard? That's porbably a good place to start.

Comment: Good point. Let me first do some tests to narrow down the scope.

Comment: At the bottom of the screen in interface builder. What do you have the size class set to? The 6+ has a different size class than the other iPhones when in landscape. This is probably where the difference is. You should really do everything in AnyAny if you're not sure.

Comment: A tons of thanks!  I used the compact width, any height. That is the problem. Your reply is the correct answer.